# PySpark giving incorrect result on rank for big data

Tags: pyspark, window, aws-glue, rank

I have a data set with 10000000 rows with a column ROWNUM that have a 0 or 1. Sometimes the window give the correct answer on order by other times she mix and take the 0 first.

[PK0, PK1, PK2, PK3, PK4, PK5, PK6. PK7, A, B,C,D,E, ROW_NUM]

```
window = Window.partitionBy(primary_keys).orderBy(desc(job_constants.ROW_NUM))
return df_uniondata.withColumn(job_constants.RANK, rank().over(window)).where(col(job_constants.RANK) == 1)
.coalesce(coalesce_count).select(df_all_changes.columns)
```

Is window() idempotent?
How can i enforce orderby on rank?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: is `job_constants` the dataframe name? could you try with just `func.col('row_num')`? the order by should give you same results every time for an unchanged dataframe.

Comment: job_constants is where glue store the collumns,  we can understant this way func.col('row_num') is the same .